# What is the origin of the phrase "(strength) on the part of"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, phrase-origin

It suddenly popped into my mind when I wanted to acknowledge my colleague's strength and determination in face of adversity and sickness. I am curious about where the phrase "(strength) on the part of" comes from.

A quick google search for *strength on the part of phrase* and *"strength on part" phrase* did not give very promising results. One of the top results is a different unrelated phrase from *[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/on-the-strength-of)*:

> **on the strength of** 
> based on what you saw, heard, experienced etc 
> *I heard their new single, and on the strength of that I bought the album.*

Sample sentences :

- The limited use of machines to replace tasks done by workers means that the work requires a lot of strength on the part of the worker. - *[libcom.org](https://libcom.org/article/housing-monster-proleinfo)*
- This required great Courage, Skill & Strength on part of the #TeamIAF. - *[twitter.com](https://twitter.com/iaf_mcc/status/931916019882328064)*
- Changes in manikin drag performance seem to be associated with improvement
  in overall upper torso muscular strength on part of the participants from both groups. - *[apps.dtic.mil](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA163110.pdf)*
- In such a case it requires a great disparity of size and strength on part of the slayer, and a very violent assault on part of his assailant, to excuse it. - *[Select American Cases on the Law of Self-defence (by L. B. Horrigan, Seymour Dwight Thompson)](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=oRY-AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=take%20%22strength%20on%20part%22&source=bl&ots=eC-ho876FD&sig=ACfU3U2JiwIqFAG42d-EbyAZ3Hq3lBXkDA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNifemnK_5AhW5JUQIHUTDCZEQ6AF6BAgmEAM#v=onepage&q=take%20%22strength%20on%20part%22&f=false)*

Comment: "I wondered how have I acquired the phrase" Literally only you can answer that. As you can see from the Google results, this isn't a well established phrase. It might help if you add a full sentence, including the phrase, showing how you use it.

Comment: Ack. Edited the question with examples of full sentences illustrating usage. Hope this helps.

Comment: The expression is _on (the) part of_ with any quality before it, not only strength, just as your examples show.

Comment: @ermanen Thank you for the edits. Since this was my first time asking a question here, I didn't get the formatting right.

Comment: @Panda142308 No problem. You did a good job for your first question, and it is a good phrase origin question that can't be answered easily. I've just formatted better and made the question a bit more clear. You can see some formatting tips in my edit in the edit history. Here is a useful link for formatting also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase ***on the part of*** (also ***on a person's part***) goes back as early as 1385, first used by Chaucer in his epic poem *Troilus and Criseyde*. Here is the definition of the phrase and the earliest citation from *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/138188?redirectedFrom=on%20the%20part%20of#eid32053163)*:

> on the side of, as regards (a person); as far as (a specified person) is concerned; proceeding from (a specified person or party) as agent; done or committed by.
>
> *a*1425  (▸*c*1385)       G. Chaucer *Troilus & Criseyd*e (1987) iv. 181      I not on yow who that this charge leyde, But, on my part [v.r. for myn part], ye may eftsone hem telle, We usen here no wommen for to selle.

<sub>Note: The symbol ► indicates date of composition for this text (as opposed to date of documentary evidence). *c* indicates *circa*, and *a* indicates *ante*.</sub>

The earlier usages of the phrase are in the form of "on someone's part"; and the first citation in *OED* where the phrase is used as "on the part of someone" is from 1667, from John Milton's *Paradise Lost*:

> Foul distrust, and breach Disloyal on the part of Man,..On the part of Heav'n Now alienated, distance and distaste.

*OED* also lists an obsolete version of the same phrase, ***(a) of the part of*** (also ***of a person's part***), first used in the Wycliffite Bible in *a*1425.